# SQL compare string

Tags: string, oracle, oracle11g, compare, case-statement

```
CASE 
WHEN ' 1a' = ' 1a                 '
THEN 'EQUAL - but it isn´t- HELP!!!!' ELSE 'UNEQUAL'
END                     
from dual;
```

Can anybody help me, an explain to me why the DB say that these
2 strings are the same

```
' 1a' = ' 1a                 '
```

I already tried a lot of statements but I can not find out why. I searched as well in the specification of Oracle 11g but there is nothing explained like that.

Comment: Dunno. Server Collation perhaps?

Comment: why are you comparing literal strings using a SQL query in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

Because Oracle converts your string literal to a CHAR; since CHAR is of fixed length, it has to expand the shorter string to the correct length, and therefore adds spaces.
Try VARCHAR2 instead:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
  WHEN cast(' 1a' as varchar2(100)) = cast(' 1a                 ' as varchar2(100))
  THEN 'EQUAL - but it isn´t- HELP!!!!' ELSE 'UNEQUAL'
  END                     
from dual;
```

EDIT: example to illustrate the difference between CHAR(10) and VARCHAR2(10)

```
declare
  l_char1 char(10) := '1';
  l_char2 char(10) := '1    ';
  l_varchar1 varchar2(10) := '1';
  l_varchar2 varchar2(10) := '1    ';
begin
  if l_char1 = l_char2 then     
    dbms_output.put_line('char equal');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('char NOT equal');
  end if;  
  if l_varchar1 = l_varchar2 then 
    dbms_output.put_line('varchar equal');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('varchar NOT equal');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: @Lukas Eder I misread the question - fixed the answer, thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to the datatype comparison rules that specify that two string literals will, by default, be compared using `CHAR` comparison semantics http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm  "Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of datatype CHAR, NCHAR, text literals, or values returned by the USER function."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Frank Schmitt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12055788/521799) solution, read about this issue in this forum post here:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59852033114407

Another option to work around the issue is not to use a comparison predicate, but some other function performing comparisons, e.g. `DECODE()`, which doesn't coerce data types:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
  WHEN decode(' 1a', ' 1a                 ', 1, 0) = 1
  THEN 'EQUAL - but it isn´t- HELP!!!!' ELSE 'UNEQUAL'
  END                     
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information, you might refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617), which says, "Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the datatype CHAR by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics," and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI) for details blank-padded comparison semantics.